# How to debug external code after exception in .NET (vs2008)

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, .net-3.5

Have Exception thrown in my app.
In callstack I can see program stops at property's getter: **FullName.get()**

I'm trying to find out what part of code is generating exception.
But in call stack I can see only 3 entries:

3) FullName.get()
2) **[External Code]**
1) myApplication.exe

Is is a way to debug external code somehow ?

Comment: There is my own exception thrown if user has no privileges to read property

Comment: You can get probable only assembly code for something  You are calling in FullName.get()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx

This blog shows how to show framework code in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Usually external code is either the .Net framework code or some unmanaged code. If I really need to view it I use the SOS extension and WinDBG, but its rather tedious.

In your case I am pretty sure you can find the source of your exception easier, someone can help your if you provide some more details, e.g. paste the code that fails.